# How to get value from nested object in Java?

Tags: java

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {

private String name;
private String age;
private Set<Children> children;

}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Children {

    private String childrenName;
    private String childrenAge;
}
```

How to get the childrenName and childrenAge from the Person object?

for example I have another test class:

```
public class Test {
    
    Children p = new Children();
    p.setChildrenName("Nick"); //prints "Nick"

    Person p = new Person();
    Set<String> childrenNames = p.getChildren().stream()
    .map(Children::getChildrenName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()); `//gets NullPointerException`

}
```

Comment: *`gets NullPointerException`* where did you set `Person`'s children? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I set name "Nick" in Children class... I thought that I can get that from the Person class as well if this is a nested object..

Comment: Children are null since not initialized or set. So you first have have to populate childrens

Comment: "Children are null since not initialized or set. So you first have have to populate childrens" - I don't think the set needs to be populated, but it will need to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Children nick = new Children(); // Create new Child
            nick.setChildrenName("Nick"); //set name Nick
            Children maria = new Children(); // Create new Child
            maria.setChildrenName("Maria"); //set name Maria
    
            Set<Children> childrenSet = new HashSet<>(); // Create new set of Children
            childrenSet.add(nick); // add nick to the set
            childrenSet.add(maria); // add maria to the set
    
            Person father = new Person(); // create Person
            father.setChildren(childrenSet); // add children to the person
    
            Set<String> childrenNames = father.getChildren().stream()
                    .map(Children::getChildrenName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // create new set of children names
            childrenNames.forEach(System.out::println); // print names of the children
        }
    }
```

You can try that if you have any questions ask me.